# how to split php valriable value contains brackets?

Tags: php, variables, brackets

I have this value (33.8352932, -117.91450359999999) in a variable
how can I split these two number in two variable without brackets??

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: So many possibilities... regular expressions, `substr`, `explode`, `trim` in various combinations... Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried explode but it gave me the variable name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This'll do the trick:

```
$str = '(33.8352932, -117.91450359999999)';
$pieces = explode(',', str_replace(array('(', ')'), '', $str));
```

Now, `var_dump($pieces)` gives you this:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "33.8352932"
  [1]=>
  string(20) " -117.91450359999999"
}
```

Comment: You can also replace `$pieces` with `list($lat, $lng)` if you want the values to go directly into two separate variables.